# Windows driver installer not detecting arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, installation

I'm trying to program my Arduino Uno with my Windows PC. I followed all the instructions on the site. I mistakenly downloaded the .zip file and didn't unzip it, before plugging in my Arduino Uno. So naturally, no message came up. I then followed the correct procedure, but Windows driver installer does not detect the Arduino Uno. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is this a genuine Arduino or a clone? Also, why not just try deleting the zip and downloading and running the installer instead?

Comment: @JakeC genuine Arduino. I'm a newbie so you're going to have to take it slow with me.

Comment: Being that you are a newbie, I highly recommend just downloading the installer and running that. While the zip does contain the drivers, it is pretty hard to install them unless you are already familiar with manually installing drivers on Windows.

Comment: @JakeC can you direct me to where I can find the installer? I'm using a Windows machine.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software where it says "Windows Installer"

Comment: @JakeC I got it working. Thanks, your advice saved a noob llike me a lot of wasted hours.

Comment: Please feel free to answer your own question and mark it as accepted (you might have to wait a bit for this depending on reputation) especially if there was something particular about your setup that you think might help future users.

Comment: @JakeC - alternatively convert your comment into an answer as it appears to have worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment above, the drivers are not installed when using the Arduino editor from an extracted zip file. If you are feeling adventurous, they are located in the /drivers folder and you can install them manually, there are plenty of instructions elsewhere on the internet on how to do that.

My recommendation would be to just download and run the installer version of Arduino, as that will take care of registering the drivers for you. The installer can be found on the [download page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) indicated with the text "Windows Installer".